# Creating a new database with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please tell me if this is mad, but basically, I've created a custom rake task, and before it does its thing, it gives the user a warning message:

```
Warning, please back up your database before continuing
```

Just in case something does go wrong. But I thought this would be awesome:

```
Warning, please back up your database before continuing. Do you wish to create it now [Y/N]
```

and upon pressing Y, the existing database would be replicated.

I don't want to create to duplicate the tables, I literally want to create a new, pristine, isolated database so that their architecture is identical, just in-case something does go wrong.

I don't want any dependencies though, I only want to use libraries included with Rails. Could I have a simple example of how to create an empty database with RoR, if this is possible?

I can create a new database like this:

```
  require 'sqlite3'

  db = SQLite3::Database.new( "test.db" )
```

However, this will only work if the user is using sqlite3. I can detect which database they're using with

```
database_type = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name #=> sqlite3
```

and then use a case statement to execute slightly different commands for each database type, but that seems a bit elaborate, and not very dynamic. (Every single database will have to be thought up before-hand).

So can I do it through Active Record?

Comment: You know how migrations work in Rails?

Comment: Yes, and that is an option. I'd prefer it to happen all in the rake task though.